# display value of "a" in bold and different color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

```
if (Global.DigsSinceLogin > 3) {
    int a = Global.DigsSinceLogin;
    noCoachingPoints.setText("Excellent Job! \n No Coaching Points Triggered in the Last "+  a  +" Digs");}
```

Requirement:

Need to display value of "a" as 1)bold and 2)yellow color.

Is there a way i can display this value with the above changes and display in the same position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below Code

```
   if (Global.DigsSinceLogin > 3) {
    int a = Global.DigsSinceLogin;
    noCoachingPoints.setText(Html.fromHtml("Excellent Job!"+"<br>"+"  No Coaching Points Triggered in the Last "+ "<font color=yellow><B>" + a + "</B></font>"+" Digs"));}
```

Comment: Thanks...exactly what was required..Appreciate your help

Comment: /n does not work ? All the text appears in the same line after  EXCELLENT Job!/n does not work.@MathanG

Comment: use <br> for next line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`SpannableString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) or [`SpannableStringBuilder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) and apply both a [`StyleSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/StyleSpan.html) and a [`ForegroundColorSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan.html) to the text that needs special treatment. This much is pretty straightforward; I think the more difficult part will be finding the proper index of the character(s) in the string, especially when you start using localized string resources (which you should).